# Fatal error: Call to undefined method objectInfo::objectInfo()

Tags: php, object

I don't find exactly where is my problem. It seems the objectinfo is empty and
I have this error on.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method objectInfo::objectInfo() on  this line $bInfo->objectInfo($banner);
```

My sql request work fine and I verified

There my code where is the problem.

Tk

```
$parameters = array('expires_date' => '',
                    'date_scheduled' => '',
                    'banners_title' => '',
                    'banners_url' => '',
                    'banners_group' => '',
                    'banners_target' => '',
                    'banners_image' => '',
                    'banners_html_text' => '',
                    'expires_impressions' => '',
                    'banners_title_admin' => ''
                    );

  $bInfo = new objectInfo($parameters);

  $bID = HTML::sanitize($_GET['bID']);

  $Qbanner = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select banners_title,
                                       banners_url,
                                       banners_image,
                                       banners_group,
                                       banners_target,
                                       banners_html_text,
                                       status,
                                       date_format(date_scheduled, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_scheduled,
                                       date_format(expires_date, "%d/%m/%Y") as expires_date,
                                       expires_impressions,
                                       date_status_change ,
                                       customers_group_id,
                                       languages_id,
                                       banners_title_admin
                                from :table_banners
                                where banners_id = :banners_id
                                ');
  $Qbanner->bindInt(':banners_id', (int)$bID);
  $Qbanner->execute();

  $banner = $Qbanner->fetch();

  $bInfo->objectInfo($banner); // pb is here
```

Comment: The error explain itself, the method `objectInfo()` is not defined, did you include or require the script where the method is defined?

Answer (score 1):

As par i know this Fatal error occur due to the updated version of the php.
Earlier, we are able to autoload the class property by using the same function name of the class name. 
In Earlier varsion of PHP, we can able to call or define the Same Function name of the class name. 
But new the Latest version of php we can not do that. if we use the same function name of the class name and if we call this function name then it give us the fatal error like you received in this post.

So the solution is as follow.

Go to the class objectInfo ( or whatever you have )
your class file is currently have

```
class objectInfo {
   function objectInfo($object_array) {
      your function code here.....
   }
 }
```

Change the function name from objectInfo to __construct. so the entire class is looking like as below

```
class objectInfo {
       function __construct($object_array) {
            your function code here.....
       }
 }
```

currently you call the function like

```
$bInfo = new objectInfo($parameters);
$bInfo->objectInfo($banner);
```

so change above code as below.

```
$bInfo = new objectInfo($parameters);
$bInfo->__construct($banner);
```

so finally hope that your error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The line `$bInfo = new objectInfo($parameters);` created a new instance of the `objectInfo` class. Then you attempt to call the method `objectInfo()` of this class. **The error message just tells you that this class has no such method.** Can you show the source code for the class `objectInfo`?

Comment: there the class  ------       class objectInfo {
    
       public function __construct($object_array) {
          foreach ($object_array as $key => $value) {
               $this->$key = $value;
          }
        }
      }

Comment: So there is no method called `objectInfo` in this class that you can call. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: find a solution in rewriting  function objectInfo($object_array) { , just I tried to convert in php7 and I don't see the error

Comment: Why do you have to rewrite the function, doesn't it work any more? Are you familiar with basics of OOP? Otherwise it could be difficult to rewrite it as an object. I don't know what this function should do. Maybe you could show and explain the original function?